# Remove all duplicates from 2 columns in spreedsheet

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have two columns in a spreedsheet each with different values,  I need to compare the two columns and remove the duplicates from each.  I need the columns to stay separate from each other so I cant remove the duplicates and mash the two columns into one.  How do I remove the duplicates while keeping the columns separate?

Comment: Are you looking for a method to do this using VBA or do you wish to stay "inside" excel and just use formulas etc.?

Comment: @Sander I would prefer to stay in excel

Comment: Did it work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for you to do this would be to have one column next to each of your data columns where you can have the formulas.

Say that you have the data in column A and D.

In column B you can write;

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1;D:D;0);FALSE);A1;"")
```

And copy this to all rows below. In column E you can write;

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(D1;A:A;0);FALSE);D1;"")
```

And copy to all rows in E.

This will write out the value if it exists in the other column.